# Custom list plot ticks

Tags: plotting

Not as exciting as the buttocks question, but ...

For some list log plots, it is faster to calculate for certain log values. eg:

```
ListPlot[Table[Prime[n],{n,Table[10^j, {j, 1, 12}]}]
```

Is it possible to get these x-axis values to show up on the ticks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 v = Table[Prime[n], {n, Table[10^j, {j, 1, 12}]}]
 np = Table[{j, Rotate[Text[10^j], Pi/3]}, {j, 1, 12}];
 ListLogPlot[v, Ticks -> {np, Automatic}]
```

[image]

or try

```
 np = Table[{j, Text["10^" <> ToString[j]]}, {j, 1, 12}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, because you are asking about a log plot, but you aren't using `ListLogPlot` at all. Perhaps this is what you want?

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{10^j, Prime[10^j]}, {j, 1, 12}]]
```

Or even:

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{10^j, Prime[10^j]}, {j, 1, 12}], 
 Ticks -> {Table[10^j, {j, 1, 12}], Automatic}]
```

The latter sounds... maybe like what you want, but it can't be, because it produces a terrible looking x-axis.

Comment: not quite, I would like the ticks spaced evenly, but I don't know whether this is possible.

Comment: ie plotted as `ListPlot`, but with ticks at values specified.

Comment: Does my first answer not do that? Or how about any variation of the second where the `Table[10^j...]` is replaced with something evenly spaced?